How to setup the number of rows used for auto-complete in MS Office 365 Excel on Android?
When I type the string, the Excel uses the content of the cells above to autocomplete the text, suggesting one of the strings from above.
It seems that the number of cells used to collect this text is very limited (I guess, about 50 lines).
How to change this value and make it start from the very first line (or at least make it the largest possible)?

You cannot change the number of rows used for autocomplete in Microsoft Office 365 Excel on Android. The feature is not customizable, and Excel has a fixed limit on the number of rows it uses for autocomplete suggestions.

Thank you. What's you source? Don't get me wrong, I need to be sure that there is no solution for the problem before I give up on it.
